# Split documents in Word 2007

Tags: word-2007, word-automation

I have a couple of word documents and want to refer to and view specific sections of these. I thought about splitting the sections into seperate documents and then just viewing the correct files but is it possible to do it a nicer way?

I thought about command-line switches for scrolling down to the correct chapter but haven't found any.

Is it possible to hide sections of a document using the word api? that way i can only show the correct sections.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you're looking for but there are few good software which may help you!

**http://microsoft1.software.informer.com/download-microsoft-word-wordperfect-converter-wpd-doc/  - Great Tools**

gregmaxey.mvps.org/Document_Splitter.htm

download3k.com/Business-Finance/Office-Suites/Download-MS-Word-Split-Divide-Save-Pages-Into-Separate-Files-Software.html